# The best way to save all users visited a page?

Tags: database, cookies, database-performance

I have a project where some users can publish a deal and I need to show the other users all the new deals. If they visit a deal page they will never see that deal as a new one. So I need to record all the users visited a deal but I don't know what's the best way. I thought to save all the visited deals by a user in the database but it would be huge table. The other option is using cookies but user can't get the right information if they login somewhere else.

Please let me know if you have any idea about this.

Comment: I asked your question more generically here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748022/quickest-sparse-matrix-access-when-disk-is-involved - it seems there is no ideal solution and although lots of people have those issue in different use cases nobody maximised and balanced performance consideration conceptionally so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really worried about too big tables you could remove expired deals(I assume 'deals' will only be there a certain amount of time)

You could also save a timestamp of the user when he/she last saw the deals page.
And upon loading, show the deals that were published after that timestamp

Comment: Removing the expired deals is our last option as we loose these information and also we need to write a script that checks the database time to time and removes the extra data and we don't like that.

about the second option we want to flag a deal as seen only if they click on the deal not when they visit the deal page